# Using nested ternary operators

Tags: php

I've been trying to use `isset()` in nested form like below:

```
isset($_POST['selectedTemplate'])?$_POST['selectedTemplate']:isset($_GET['selectedTemplate'])?$_GET['selectedTemplate']:0
```

But seems I'm missing something. Can anyone assist me how to do it?

Comment: Please don't use one-liners for that. It's unreadable.

Comment: Nesting the ternary operator really isn't recommended because it is completely non-intuitive: if you need to nest, you really should use full if/else syntax because it's much easier to read both for yourself and others

Comment: This bears the question why your form can be submitted via POST and GET in the first place. [HTTP verbs have certain semantics to them.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Wrap it in parentheses:

```php
$selectedTemplate = isset($_POST['selectedTemplate'])
                  ? $_POST['selectedTemplate']
                  : (
                       isset($_GET['selectedTemplate'])
                       ? $_GET['selectedTemplate']
                       : 0
                  );
```

Or even better, use a proper `if`/`else` statement (for maintainability):

```php
$selectTemplate = 0;

if (isset($_POST['selectedTemplate'])) {
    $selectTemplate = $_POST['selectedTemplate'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['selectedTemplate'])) {
    $selectTemplate = $_GET['selectedTemplate'];
}
```

---

However, as others have pointed out: it would simply be easier for you to use `$_REQUEST`:

```php
$selectedTemplate = isset($_REQUEST['selectedTemplate'])
                  ? $_REQUEST['selectedTemplate']
                  : 0;
```

Comment: Just a note: `$_REQUEST` takes more than `$_POST` and `$_GET` and the order can vary.

Comment: Cheers. Exactly what I needed, I did not know you had to wrap the whole second part of the statement in parenthesis.

Comment: Good on the maintainability.

Comment: C/C++ don't need parens for nested ?:, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18237432/2097284, so someone who comes to PHP from there gets a surprise.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune - C/C++ uses right-associativity by default for ternary expressions, while PHP uses left-associativity by default. In reality, left-associativity is almost never what you want, so PHP's default doesn't really make much sense. In fact, [this is being deprecated in PHP 7.4](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ternary_associativity).

Comment: Finally - The bug is now "deprecated". And will be fixed in like 20 years (version 9.0?).

Answer (score 10):

As of `PHP 7` we can use [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```
$selectedTemplate = $_POST['selectedTemplate'] ?? $_GET['selectedTemplate'] ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

A little investigate here, and I guess, I've found real answer :)

Example code:

```php
<?php

$test = array();
$test['a'] = "value";


var_dump(
    isset($test['a'])
        ? $test['a']
        : isset($test['b'])
            ? $test['b']
            : "default"
);
```

### Be attentive to round brackets, that I've put.

I guess, you're waiting to get similar behavior:

```
var_dump(
    isset($test['a'])
        ? $test['a']
        : (isset($test['b'])  // <--  here
            ? $test['b']
            : "default")      // <--  and here
);
```

---

**But!** Real behavior looks like this:

```
var_dump(
    (isset($test['a'])        // <--  here
        ? $test['a']
        : isset($test['b']))  // <--  and here
            ? $test['b']
            : "default"
);
```

---

General mistake was, that you've missed notice: **Undefined index**.

[Online shell](https://3v4l.org/jsJR2).

Answer (score 4):

It's simpler to read if we write ternary in the following manner:

```
$myvar = ($x == $y)
  ?(($x == $z)?'both':'foo')
  :(($x == $z)?'bar':'none');
```

But ternary operators are short, effective ways to write simple if statements. They are not built for nesting. :)

Answer (score 3):

You might have an easier time simply using the $_REQUEST variables:

> > "$_REQUEST is an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE."

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work:

```
$test = array();
$test['a'] = 123;
$test['b'] = NULL;


$var = (isset($test['a']) ? $test['a'] : (!isnull($test['b']) ? $test['b'] : "default"));

echo $var;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the ternary with the ambiguous precedence, you could just use [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/_REQUEST) instead of the fiddly $_GET and $_POST probing:

```
 isset($_REQUEST['selectedTemplate']) ? $_REQUEST['selectedTemplate'] : 0
```

This is precisely what it is for.