# Uunderstand the limits of the ? operator

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

if say I had a function that would ultimately come true could I do something like this?

```
somefunction(data) ? cout << "This is true" << endl : cout << this false << endl;
```

or am I little off? or is this impossible with such said operand? or could I call a different function? Ultimately, I a trying to figure out the limitations of this functions and other uses that aren't apparent in the c++ tutorial site.

std::cout<< (somefunction(data) ? "This is true" : anotherfunction (data) <

or other cases that people can think of...

Comment: `std::cout<< (somefunction(data) ? "This is true" : "this is false") <<std::endl;`

Comment: `std::cout << "This is " << std::boolalpha << somefunction(data) << '\n';`

Comment: Experimenting is fine, but in practice, use an if statement for that kind of code.

Comment: @NeilKirk Why? I don't see it as a bad habit unless you are nesting ridiculously like in my answer

Comment: You would write the example code on one line instead of `if (somefunction(data)) ..` ?? Personally, not my style.

Comment: @NeilKirk I suppose... I do usually find myself with one-liner `if-else` statements to just put in a line under indented to make it more readable.... But I think if it is something dealing with bools such as: `bool b = 1 < 2 ? true : false;` then that is more readable

Comment: I use `bool b = (1 < 2);`

Comment: @NeilKirk I would too.  But I suspect that (1 < 2) is actually an int which gets implicitly converted into a bool.  I guess Outlaw has some justification in making that conversion explicit.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala No it's a bool.

Comment: Well, I probably wouldn't nest as much as @OutlawLemur did as I would probably confuse myself lol. However, you guys (and I say that in a gender free kinda of way) gave some good answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Pipsydoodles Its good for obfuscation;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.2B.2B). Basically it's syntax is

```
condition ? trueOutput : falseOutput;
```

Also you can [nest them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237432/how-to-rewrite-complicated-lines-of-c-code-nested-ternary-operator). You can output any value, but the condition has to be a boolean.

So in your case it would be:

```
cout << (someFunction(data) ? "True" : "False") << endl;
```

You can then nest this even!

```
cout << (someFunction(data) ? "True" : (newTernary(data) ? "False, but true" : (finalTernary(data) ? "False, false, and finally true" : "Always false:("))) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an "answer", but bear in mind that nearly always, using ternary operators for anything beyond the most simple things is "bad".

Reasonable usage is something like:

```
cout << "There are " << count << " item" << ((count != 1) ? "s":"") 
     << " in your basket";
```

But if your ternary operators are nested, then you want to use `if`/`else` type constructs instead. People will want to read the the code without pulling their hair out in the future!

Of course, the initial statement can be done without ternary operators, assuming the result is a `bool` [and if it isn't, you could make it to a `bool` with a `static_cast<bool>(someFunction(data))`].

```
cout << "This is " << boolalpha << someFunction(data) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "limitation" is that the three arguments have to be expressions, and there are rules about their types.  In your case, that all works out since `cout << foo` is an expression. Although you need to replace `this false` with "this is false".

But as others have pointed out, it is better to use the bare strings as your expressions.  I might have written

```
std::cout << "This is " << (somefunction(data) ? "true" : "false") << ".\n";
```