# What is the accepted formatting for nested ternary-operators?

Tags: javascript, formatting, ternary-operator

Say we have nested ternary statements:

```
return foo ? 1 : bar ? 2 : 3;
```

What is the best way to format this code to ensure future readability by others.

Comment: Don't do that. Nested ternary statements seriously hurt readability.

Comment: Please read [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/is-using-the-ternary-operator-like-this-considered-less-readable) codereview post.

Comment: This looks to be opinion based without a "correct" answer, or best decision made on a case by case basis (my _opinion_). @ariberiro supplied link to codereview discusses the topic further.

Answer (score 13):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18237507/2517147) is the most popular opinion I could find on this.  The suggestion there is

```
return foo ? 1 :
       bar ? 2 : 
             3 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return foo ? 1 : (bar ? 2 : 3) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To separate function

```
function getValue(cond1, cond2) {
  if(cond1) return 'a';
  if(cond2) return 'b';
  return 'c';
}

function work() {
  const result = getValue(/* some params */);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a preference for the readability of this style of ternary operator formatting:

```
return foo
    ? bar
    : baz
      ? qux
      : qiz
        ? 1
        : 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell if this is accepted or not but i use it this way all the time.

Ternary gives you such a natural testing structure that you can make the code very readable just by making it multiline and indenting properly. I strongly believe that the following usage of ternary is the best manifestation of a nested conditional.

```
return foo ? 1 
           : bar ? 2
                 : 3;
```

In more complicated cases you can make ternary and comma operator work together beautifully. Keep in mind that the last instruction in a comma separated group gets returned automatically. Super handy for ternary.

```
return foo ? ( doSometingFoo()
             , variable++
             , collectResult()               // and return foo result
             )
           : bar ? ( doSomethingBar()
                   , variable--
                   , collectAnotherResult()  // and return bar result
                   )
                 : ( doSomethingReject()
                   , variable = 0
                   , rejectSomehow()         // and return error code
                   )
```

Comment: This kind of works for like three levels but quickly breaks down when you have more than three legs due to excessive indenting. Lining it up like this answer is better for handling an arbitrary number of legs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724098

Answer (score -3):

For readability just stay away from those statements, they're very easy to misread, if you want something more readable just expand and use normal statments..

Nothing wrong with just having a nested if statement list..

```
if(foo){
   return 1
}else{
  if(bar){
      return 2;
  }else{
      return 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: Usage of multiple if's instead of ternary operators is contraindicated by some languages due to performance concerns (e.g. QML)