Get Visual Studio Code to format nested conditionals on the same level
Consider JavaScript code like this:
const folder = cookieSorted.branded.includes(cookie.name) ? "Branded" :
    cookieSorted.christmas.includes(cookie.name) ? "Christmas" :
    cookieSorted.danishButter.includes(cookie.name) ? "Butter" :
    cookieSorted.holloween.includes(cookie.name) ? "Halloween" : "Other";

Unfortunately, the Visual Studio Code autoformatter insists on formatting it as follows:
const folder = cookieSorted.branded.includes(cookie.name) ? "Branded" :
    cookieSorted.christmas.includes(cookie.name) ? "Christmas" :
        cookieSorted.danishButter.includes(cookie.name) ? "Butter" :
            cookieSorted.holloween.includes(cookie.name) ? "Halloween" : "Other";

Is there a way to get it to place all of the conditions at the same column?

I agree, and I don't see any setting to change the behaviour.  You may have to file an issue.

I also prefer the style you're looking for; however, the use and formatting of nested ternary operators is somewhat opinionated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541443/what-is-the-accepted-formatting-for-nested-ternary-operators / https://www.sonarsource.com/blog/stop-nesting-ternaries-javascript/

@wp78de I appreciate the reply, but I’m asking how to do this in VSC, not opinions on whether I should do it.

Prettier 3.3+ seems to be able to format nested "case-style" ternaries as an experimental feature (blog, online playground with --experimental-ternaries &  "experimentalTernaries": true via API/.prettierrc).
Unfortunately, there is an open issue in the VSCode Plugin and the experimental feature does not work using vanilla Prettier.  This SO QA suggests some alternatives like using prettierx or prettier-plugin-x. It's unfortunate, but this won't be an issue when the experimental Prettier style becomes the default and the feature works in VSCode as intended soon (hopefully).
I planned to add this as a comment but it's too long and using Prettier(x) can solve the problem (today), not out of the box, but with some extra effort.
