# Assignment in ternary operator

Tags: c, conditional-operator

For a ternary operator, why does the following compile:

```
a > b ? a=4 : ' ';
```

But this one does not:

```
a > b ? ' ' : b=4;
```

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

That is, what makes the `true` case different than the `false` case for assignment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has to do with the formal definition of the conditional operator.  From section 6.5.15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ```
> conditional-expression:
>   logical-OR-expression
>   logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
> ```

The second clause of a conditional can be any expression, while the third clause can only be a conditional expression (of which as assignment is not).  Put another way, the conditional operator `?:` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.

So this:

```
a > b ? a=4 : ' '
```

Is the same as this:

```
(a > b) ? (a=4) : (' ')
```

But this:

```
a > b ? ' ' : b=4;
```

Is the same same as this:

```
((a > b) ? (' ') : b)=4;
```

And the result of the conditional operator cannot be assigned to (i.e. it is not an lvalue) so you get an error.

If you add parenthesis you can get something that compiles:

```
a > b ? ' ' : (b=4);
```

Granted, these statements don't look like the best use case for a conditional and should probably be rewritten as:

```
if (a>b) a=4;
```

And:

```
if (a<=b) b=4;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:?` has higher operator precedence than assignment operator. So the latter is equivalent to:

```
(a > b ? ' ' : b)=4;
```

Which is obviously illegal.

Comment: I see, so I just need parentheses to do the second case without a compiler error.

Comment: And the code can use parentheses to achieve the desired result: `a > b ? (a = 4) : ' ';` or `a > b ? ' ' : (b = 4);` (which is symmetric, even if not strictly necessary in the first case).  The parentheses avoid all risk of ambiguity to both compiler and human code reader.  It seems slightly dubious doing only one assignment (why is control-D assigned to whatever this expression is assigned to), but it's hard to know without more code than is shown.  It the expression is not assigned or otherwise used, then using the ternary operator is wholly inappropriate — use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

It is the case where there is an essential difference between C and C++ that you should know.:)

In C the conditional (ternary) operator is defined like

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

while in C++ like

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

So in C this statement

```
a > b ? ' ' : b=4;
```

is equivalent to

```
( a > b ? ' ' : b ) = 4;
```

So the compiler issues an error because you may not assign a value to other value.

From the C Standard (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

> 4 The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between
> its evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
> (whichever is evaluated). The second operand is evaluated only if the
> first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
> the first compares equal to 0; **the result is the value of the second
> or third operand (whichever is  evaluated)**, converted to the type
> described below

In C++ this statement is equivalent to

```
a > b ? ' ' : ( b=4 );
```

and is a valid statement.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    
    a > b ? ' ' : b=4;
    
    std::cout << "b = " << b << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
b = 4
```