# Why is using assignments in ternary operator generating an error without parentheses?

Tags: c

This is a code in C, which is generating this error:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int m =4 ; int n =5;
    int c=0;
    
m>n?c=40: c=20;    
 
 printf("%d",c);   
}
```

But when I use the brackets in ternary operator it's generating output without error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int m =4 ; int n =5;
    int c=0;
    
m>n?(c=40): (c=20);    
 
 printf("%d",c);   
}
```

Output: 20

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> m>n?c=40: c=20;
> ```

Your expression is the same as below

```
(m > n ? c = 40 : c) = 20;
((m > n) ? (c = 40) : c) = 20;
```

which may make the error more obvious.

Comment: Yes but more detailled explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891926/assignment-in-ternary-operator Should be closed for duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong. Write

```
c = (m > n) ? 40 : 20;
```

Comment: They already knew that it was wrong, the question is why.

Comment: No, his code differs from mine.