# How do nested ternary operators work in C++ if you're not using else if statements?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I’m trying to fit two lines of code into one line for code golf, but it requires using nested ternary operators, and I’m getting an “initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator ‘?’” error. I tried Googling how to use nested ternary operators, but all the results are for `if/else if/else if.../else` structures, while I want to nest them for a structure like this:

```
if (…) {
   // return something
} else {
   if (…) { // this if/else is already using a ternary operator
      // return something
   } else {
      // return something
   } 
}
```

For context, the two lines of code look like this right now:

```
if (...) return {elem};
return (...) ? recursive call + recursive call : recursive call;
```

Comment: Does it work if you add parenthesis around `(recursive call + recursive call)`? Also, can you give the actual lines of code in question?

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere in the code that you did *not* post. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You provided what looks like the exact (copy-paste) error message, which is good. Please also provide (minimal) code that produces that error message; otherwise the only possible answers are wild guesses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rewrite complicated lines of C++ code (nested ternary operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237432/how-to-rewrite-complicated-lines-of-c-code-nested-ternary-operator)

Comment: I'm going to vote to close because you didn't provide an actual code example that elicits the error you claim to be receiving.  Edit your question and provide a real example of the bogus syntax, and then we'll re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

There isn't nested ternary operators in C++, but you can combine them;

```
return firstcondition ? a : (secondcondition ? b : c);
```

or without redundant parantheses;

```
return firstcondition ? a : secondcondition ? b : c;
```

it is same with;

```
if (firstcondition) {
    return a;
} else {
    if (secondcondition) {
       return b;
    } else {
       return c;
    }
}
```

also, you can write it like;

```
if (firstcondition) {
    return a;
} else if (secondcondition) {
    return b;
} else {
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Parens are unnecessary and distracting in my view, `return firstcondition ? a : secondcondition ? b : c;` is fine.

Comment: @john right, but I think it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use nested ternary operator, you should understand its purpose.

- You should use it, while assigning some values to variables.
- On the other hand, if-else statement can be used for other things.

While, I would insist you not to use ternary for complex or multiple operations, but, since you need it, here it may help you.

A normal ternary statement:

```
int c = (a1>a2) ? a1:a2;
```

Its, if-else equivalent will be,

```
if(a1>a2){
     c = a1;
}
else {
     c = a2;
}
```

Now, a complex operation,

A if-else statement to find the leap year

```
 if (year % 400 == 0) {
   cout<<"Leap Year";
 }
 else if (year % 100 == 0) {
   cout<<"Not a leap Year";
 }
 else if (year % 4 == 0) {
  cout<<"Leap Year";
 }
 else {
    cout<<"Not a leap Year";
 }
```

Now the same using ternary operator,

```
(year%4==0 && year%100!=0) ? cout<<"Leap Year" : (year%400 ==0 ) ? cout<<"Leap Year" : cout<<"not a leap year";
```

Comment: Oh ok, it works fine in C, but if you look at tags this question is about C++.

Comment: Code updated, now it will work. Although printf() works in C++.