# How to use AND in if statement using ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I write this if statement inside echo statement, but it did not work correctly.
Given that $row['a']=0 and $row['b']=0 from database.

`.($row['a']==0 && $row['b']==0?'waiting for approval':$row['a']==1 && $row['b']==1?'Approved':'Stop running').`

But it always echo Approved? It should echo 'waiting for approval' Is there something wrong with my code? Please help... many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using nested ternary operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735280/using-nested-ternary-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more parenthesis

```
.(($row['a'] == 0 && $row['b'] == 0) ? 'waiting for approval' : (($row['a'] == 1 && $row['b'] == 1) ? 'Approved':'Stop running')).
```