# Complex ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have use this ternary operator. To check my length variable `$len`, based on that return values

My length is taken from

```
$len = strlen($indChar); // values up to 3 ... 8
```

when it pass the value of 3 it strangely returns 30

```
$lft = ($len <= 4) ? 10 : 
       ((5 <= $len) && ($len <= 6)) ? 20 : 
       ((7 <= $len) && ($len <= 8)) ? 30 : 35;

var_dump($lft); //30
```

I don't know what I did wrong. If anything wrong please correct me.

Comment: Well it will always return 30, you got `<=` condition doubled. Try this `(5 >= $len) && ($len <= 6)` and `(7 >= $len) && ($len <= 8)`

Comment: Each expression must be contained in parenthesis.

Comment: If you would read the php documentation and other literature (on-/offline) you would have noticed that complex ternary operations are strongly discouraged... Not just because of readability, but also because it's very error-prone. If you need to compare more than one, use regular conditions (if-else)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using nested ternary operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735280/using-nested-ternary-operators)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using the conditions. Enclose each condition in separate brackets.

```
$len = 3
$lft = ($len <= 4) ? 10 : 
    (((5 <= $len) && ($len <= 6)) ? 20 : 
    (((7 <= $len) && ($len <= 8)) ? 30 : 35));
echo $lft; // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `()` to specify the conditions separately. Try with -

```
$len = 3;
$lft = ($len <= 4) ? 10 : 
       (((5 <= $len) && ($len <= 6)) ? 20 : 
       (((7 <= $len) && ($len <= 8)) ? 30 : 35));
echo $lft; // 10
```

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:

[DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

[Check it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#PHP)