# How to use ternary operators if-elseif-else in php?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to use ternary operator for if-elseif-else. But it is not working for me.

Kindly check the code below:

```
$openMon = "00:01";  // The below Line Returns Time
$openMon = "00:00";  // The below Line Returns Close

<td><?=(($openMon == '00:00')?'Close':date("g:i a", strtotime($openMon)));?></td>
```

The above line working perfectly because it returns True or false.

**But when $openMon blank it returns 1am. I want when $openMon blank it returns "-"**

I want Three Things in one line like:

```
$openMon = "";        // This is I want in ternary operator with above two conditions

if($openMon == "" ){
    $openMon ="-";
}
```

I tried:

```
<td><?=isset((openMon == "")?'-':(($openMon == '00:00')?'Close':date("g:i a", strtotime($openMon)));?></td>
```

This is not working for me.

Basically I want in ternary operator:

```
if($openMon == ''){
    $openMon = "-";
}else{
    if($openMon == '00:00'){
        $openMon = "Close";
    }else{
        $openMon = date("g:i a", strtotime($openMon)));
    }
}
```

Any Idea or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Ternary... But why do you want a messy ternary when you have an if else that does the same thing in a cleaner and easier to read way?

Comment: @ Andreas Thank you for the response. I am learning the code so I want to learn how to use these things in a single line.

Comment: `isset((openMon == "")` Does that work in your `if` loop? (Missing a `$`). Also don't "ask" if `openMon == ""` is set. Ask if `$openMon` is set. Or if `$openMon == ""`. You're doing both

Comment: Single line is a messy way to code and you will regret it when you need to debug or change something. I strongly advice you to not use ternary if it's more than two conditions. And me personally don't ever use it unless... well I don't know how to finnsih that...

Comment: @ kerbholz thank you for the response. My if-else working fine but I want to use in turnary operator. If-elseif-else.

Comment: @kerbholz  $openMon = ""; is the right one. openMon was a typing error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use nested ternary operator.
Same question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735280/using-nested-ternary-operators).

Your code will be like this:

```
$openMon = !$openMon ? "-" : ($openMon == '00:00' ? "Close" : date("g:i a", strtotime($openMon)))
```

Your can test this code snippet [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/281be0402c392f4ca5c911cb0ec70d040ced2fcb).

Comment: thanks for the reply. You are a great coder. I wanted to learn and you taught me. Thank You.

Comment: Have a nice coding! Best regards.)